# laravel virtualhost 404 error

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, apache2

I have apache2 on my ubuntu server.

There is my /etc/apache2/sites-available/laravel.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName http://laravel.mysite.com/
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/laravel/public"
    <Directory "/var/www/laravel/public">
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
      　Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and I have open the apache's mod_rewrite function.

There is my /var/www/laravel/app/routes.php

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('home/index');
});
Route::get('/hehe', function()
{
    return "hehe';
});
```

There is my /var/www/laravel/public/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and now, I can visit the http://laravel.mysite.com, but when I visit the http://laravel.mysite.com/hehe, it gives the 404 error. Is there anything I config wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Although the question is very old, for anyone still interested (as was me, but managed to solve the problem), I created a checklist to go through if Laravel routes throw a 404 or 403 error.

I assume that Laravel's originally installed `public/.htaccess` file is unmodified.

1. Be sure to insert the <Directory> section into the virtual host's apache config file with the proper path.
2. Be sure to have `AllowOverride All`, and not `None` in the <Directory> section to allow routes (avoiding 404 error).
3. Be sure to have `Require all granted`, and not `denied` in the <Directory> section to give permission visitors to see the site (avoiding 403 error).
4. It may also be necessary to include `Options FollowSymLinks` in the <Directory> section if you use symlinks in your app.
5. Be sure to have the `rewrite` module enabled in apache: `$ sudo a2enmod rewrite`
6. And don't forget to restart the apache server for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i do is to devise the apache2.conf, add this:

```
<Directory /var/www/laravel/public>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```